# Como obtener una cuenta GMAIL ya registrada en el dispositivo?

Tags: android

Lo que quiero es que, en vez de ingresar el email y la contraseña (`"xxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxpassword"`), directo en el código,
**usar el email ya registrado por el usuario en el teléfono**, espero su ayuda gracias.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try {
        GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("xxxx@gmail.com", 
 "xxxxpassword");
        sender.sendMail("This is a testing mail",
                "This is Body of testing 
 mail","oskr.developer1024@gmail.com",
                "oskr.developer1024@gmail.com")                   ;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error", e.getMessage(), e);
        return "Email No Enviado";
    }
    return "Email Enviado";
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Log.e("LongOperation",result+"");
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

}
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
 }
 }
```

Comment: Te refieres al email con el que has iniciado sesion en tu cuenta de google de tu teléfono? en tal caso: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating  
Si por el contrario te refieres a un email que diste de alta en un proceso de registro en tu aplicacion movil, deberías usar las SharedPreferences

Comment: si existiera la opción de sacar el user/pass de la cuenta del teléfono, cuantos usuarios hackeados existirían? :D

Comment: Hermano Corpex, lo que que quiero es que mi aplicacion reconozca las cuentas ya registradas en el telefono y que pueda seleccionar una de ellas para usarla en mi aplicacion, osea q muestre la lista de cuentas registradas y que el usuario pueda elegir cual de esas cuantas usara para que mi aplicacion le envie la informacion.

Comment: Amigo diegoveloper, te fuiste por otro camino jaja, en mi prigunta pido usar el email ya registrado por el usuario, en ningun momento pido contraseña, saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Para ingresar el email del usuario primeramente debes obtenerlo, pero debes recordar que un dispositivo puede tener varias cuentas de email configuradas en el mismo, por ejemplo este dispositivo tiene 2 cuentas registradas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso, si se tiene más de una cuenta, se puede obtener la principal:

```
String  emailAccount = "";
        AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
        Account account = getAccount(accountManager);
        if (account != null) {
            emailAccount =  account.name;
        }
```

este es el método `getAccount()` :

```
private static Account getAccount(AccountManager accountManager) {
    Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    Account account;
    if (accounts.length > 0) {
        account = accounts[0];
    } else {
        account = null;
    }
    return account;
}
```

De esta forma obtendrías la cuenta principal registrada en el dispositivo.